# Format Stones and Pounds correctly?

Tags: delphi, math, delphi-xe, type-conversion

I have a chart used to display weight in Stones and Pounds (lbs).

The chart is populated by data from a record, for weight the data type is Double.

The record data is edited at runtime and I need to know a way of formatting the entered data correctly.

To better understand, first look at these sample values, they are represented as Stones and lbs:

- 8.09 (8 stones and 9 lbs)
- 12.03 (12 stones and 3 lbs)
- 14.16 (14 stones and 16 lbs)
- 11.13 (11 stones and 13 lbs)
- 17.14 (17 stones and 14 lbs)

There are only 14 pounds in a stone, so any value entered that is over .13 should increase the stones value by 1 and lower the pounds value starting back from .00 - so with that in mind, from the above sample two of those values are incorrect:

- 14.16
- 17.14

they should be:

- 15.02
- 18.00

Is there a built-in math function that can correctly format/round stones and pounds correctly?

If not I would be really interested to see an answer that shows the logic or method of approach to solving this.

I thought of checking the pounds part and if the value > 0.13 then I increment the stones, but then I am not sure how best to do this especially, if the value could be something like 13.76 then I wouldn't know what to change the stones and pounds into (this is where I start to confuse myself).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A question that remains unanswered in my mind is why you are using this notation for st/lbs - you say you have a chart which takes a double type and you intend to use this chart to graph weight.  Are you hoping that the above formulation of st/lbs will be suitable to use for charting purposes, or is it simply for display purposes?  Putting `12.03` into a `double` to mean 12st,3lbs will not chart correctly on any chart (there would be huge chasms between integer stones and all the lbs data would bunch into a small slice at each interval).  For charting you would need to choose either lbs or st.

Comment: @J That's the decision I made thinking that float/double was suitable, but having read some of the comments maybe it was the wrong choice. But I totally see your point and this almost brings me to asking another question because the left axis on the chart increments like: `5.0, 5.1, 5.2, .., 5.8, 5.9` etc. If I am representing the values as 12.04 (stones and lbs) the chart is always going to look like a flat line, as you described above basically.

Comment: Well, I don't think another answer is in order - there is enough information below to demonstrate how to make the conversions.  Rather than make your users input data in this format, however, it may be much simpler to have two input boxes - one for st. and one for lbs.  It is then easy to validate the lbs box for a value less than 14.  For storing, however, you should use a plain float (like David's `weight:=stones + pounds/14`).  This would plot, for example 8st7lbs as a value of 8.50 - halfway between 8 and 9 st.  You can always reverse the conversion to display in st-lbs format elsewhere.

Comment: In fact, to make it silly-proof you could even use a combobox for the lbs value.  You only need to have 14 items so it's a no-brainer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For pounds you get the fractional part with `Frac(weight)` and then multiply by 100. Then use `Round` to get it in integer form:

```
pounds := Round(100*Frac(weight));
```

And for stones it's just `Trunc`:

```
stones := Trunc(weight);
```

In the other direction you do:

```
weight := stones + pounds/100.0;
```

With these functions you can readily do the rest. The validity checks for values of pounds greater than 14 are easy to deal with. For example:

```
stones := Trunc(weight);
pounds := Round(100*Frac(weight));
stones := stones + pounds div 14;
pounds := pounds mod 14;
```

I'd be very surprised if you found this code anywhere in a general purpose library. That's because it's a very poor way to store weight. If you are going to use a floating point format you should do it like this:

```
weight := stones + pounds/14.0;
```

In the other direction you would do it like this:

```
stones := Trunc(weight);
pounds := Round(14*Frac(weight));
stones := stones + pounds div 14;
pounds := pounds mod 14;
```

Unfortunately you still need to do the div/mod shuffle. Imagine what happens when `weight=9.99`, for example.

Doing it this way makes arithmetic on the floating point values more sensible. For example, suppose you have measured weights of 10 people and want to know the total. It makes sense to do that with true floating point representation, but not with your representation.

To see that, suppose these 10 people, and they all weigh zero stones, 10 pounds. Very small people I know. But you would call that 0.1. Add up 10 lots of that and you have a weight of 1.0. But it's clear that the actual value is 100 pounds, or 7 stone two pounds.

But if you take 10 pounds and feed it into:

```
weight := stones + pounds/14.0;
```

then you find a weight value of 10/14. Add 10 lots of that to get 100/14, and well, I'm sure you get my drift!

The other obvious way to store such data is as pounds. Either integers or floating point could make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Or you COULD do something like this :-)

```
unit PoundsAndStones;

interface

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TPoundStone = record
  private
    FWeight : double;
    function GetPounds: integer;
    procedure SetPounds(const Value: integer);
    function GetStones: integer;
    procedure SetStones(const Value: integer);
    procedure SetWeight(const Value: double);
    function GetString: string;
  public
    property Weight : double read FWeight write SetWeight;   //Weight in stones.pounds format
    property Stones : integer read GetStones write SetStones; //Weight in stones, fraction part ignored
    property Pounds : integer read GetPounds write SetPounds; //Weight in pounds
    property AsString : string read GetString;

    class operator Implicit(A : double) : TPoundStone;
    class operator Implicit(A : TPoundStone) : double;
    class operator Add(A, B: TPoundStone): TPoundStone;
  end;

implementation

class operator TPoundStone.Add(A, B: TPoundStone): TPoundStone;
begin
  Result.Weight := A.Weight + B.Weight;
end;

function TPoundStone.GetPounds: integer;
begin
  Result := round(frac(FWeight)*100);
end;

function TPoundStone.GetStones: integer;
begin
  Result := trunc(FWeight);
end;

function TPoundStone.GetString: string;
var
  P,S : string;
begin
  if Stones > 1 then
    S := inttostr(Stones)+' stones'
  else if Stones = 1 then
    S := '1 stone'
  else
    S := '';

  if Pounds > 1 then
    P := inttostr(Pounds)+' pounds'
  else if Pounds = 1 then
    P := '1 pound'
  else
    P := '';

  if (P > '') and (S > '') then
    Result := S + ' and ' + P
  else
    Result := S + P;
end;

class operator TPoundStone.Implicit(A: double): TPoundStone;
begin
  Result.FWeight := A;
end;

class operator TPoundStone.Implicit(A: TPoundStone): double;
begin
  Result := A.FWeight;
end;

procedure TPoundStone.SetWeight(const Value : double);
var
  P,S : integer;
begin
  S := trunc(Value);
  P := round(100*frac(Value));

  S := S + P div 14;
  P := P mod 14;

  FWeight := S + P/100.0;
end;

procedure TPoundStone.SetPounds(const Value: integer);
var
  P,S : integer;
begin
  S := Value div 14;
  P := Value mod 14;

  FWeight := S + P/100.0;
end;

procedure TPoundStone.SetStones(const Value: integer);
begin
  Weight := Value*14;
end;

end.
```

Which would allow you to do stuff like this

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  PoundsAndStones in 'PoundsAndStones.pas';

var
  P0,P1,P2 : TPoundStone;

begin
  P0 := 1.05;
  P1 := 3.12;

  writeln(P0.AsString);
  writeln(P1.AsString);

  P2 := P0 + P1;
  writeln(P2.AsString);
end.
```

which would output this:

```
1 stone and 5 pounds
3 stones and 12 pounds
5 stones and 3 pounds
```

Comment: Classy answer.  I like this.

Comment: What I don't like about this is the way that the weight is stored. The  representation given in the question is very poor and I don't like the fact that you have continued to use it without question. At the very least you should add some text to say that it's a bad idea. Now, the natural way to store the underlying data, given the code in this answer, is a single integer storing the number of pounds.

Comment: There are some things in there I have never seen before, like `class operator`.

Comment: Operator overloading is very nice indeed. But right now, @Blobby, you need to get on top of the mathematical representation of weight. Your most recent [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509367/setting-the-left-axis-on-a-tchart-to-increment-the-decimal-value-up-to-13) has allowed me to produce an answer that I hope will make it clear to you the folly of your current approach.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it makes things a lot more clearer. I was too focused on how it should visually look rather than how the internals should be written. I am following your answers in close detail and making the changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
function tostonesandpounds(p_value : double) : double;
var
  stone : integer;
  pounds : integer;
begin
  stone := trunc(p_value);
  pounds := trunc(100.0*(p_value + 0.009));
  pounds := pounds-(stone*100);
  inc(stone,(pounds div 14));
  pounds := pounds mod 14;
  result := stone + (pounds/100.0);
end;
```